# Specific Domain User Cannot Log into Specific Domain PCs

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, credentials

Good morning,

I have an employee who occasionally signs into different computers throughout our office depending where they are working that day (e.g. reception, checkout, etc.) but there are 4 PCs in particular that when they enter their domain login credentials, Windows 10 simply spins (as far as I know, indefinitely - they've let it go for over an hour) and will not log them in. The PC needs to be hard shutdown/powered on in order for us to get back to the login screen. In this event, they will have someone else log in under their credentials so they can work at that work station.

I verified the DNS was dynamic, (although, as I'm writing this, I'm wondering if I should simply disjoin, then rejoin those PCs to the domain and test), but otherwise, I'm truly at a loss as to why they can sign into some PCs and not into others. There have not been any changes to these computers (other than Windows Updates) over the last ~2 years since they've been installed.

A simpler breakdown might be:

- [Employee A] can log into [Computer A]
- [Employee A] cannot log into [Computer B], [Computer C]
- [Employee B] can log into [Computer A], [Computer B], and [Computer C]

Any thoughts or starting points? We are running Windows Server 2008R2 Standard as the main domain controller. Is there any chance it could be related to the active-directory account? Happy to provide more info, of course.

-JP

Comment: Did you check the eventlogs?

Comment: I didn't but only because when they sign in, it spins, then we have to hard reboot the PC. At that moment I didn't have time to sit and wait for it to come back up, but I will get with the individual and try this again, then check the logs. That's a good idea, I didn't really think to start there

Comment: You can view the logs remotely without bothering the user. Just launch event viewer as an account with administrative privileges on the workstation and connect to the remote computer. Also, the issue as described sounds like it could be user profile corruption. The logs should help narrow it down.

Comment: Logs aren't showing me anything outrageously obvious, whether they're system or security. I removed the PC from the domain, rebooted, deleted the User Profile, rebooted, re-added to the domain, rebooted, tried signing back in, and still sits and spins. I will keep plugging away, but not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: event id 6005 the winlogon notification subscriber gpclient is taking long time to handle the notification event (logon)

This seems to be the big one I am seeing